# VC compiler CLI how to link against library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, command-line-interface

I'm simply trying to link against the SDL library using the Visual c compiler and the CLI.

The command i use is the following:

```
  cl /I "..\lib\" "..\src\*.cpp" "SDL2main.lib" /Fe "main.exe"
```

As you can see, all im trying to do is include the "..\lib" folder (which is where the SDL headers are located as well as the lib files) and then i specify what source files i want it to compile from the "src" directory and last i specify a lib i want to link against (namely the SDL2main.lib).

But when i run it i get the following output:

```
  cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename
```

I tried figuring it out myself by looking at the msdn page, but its honestly quite confusing.

Comment: I don't think `*.cpp` will work.

Comment: it was working fine before i tried linking against a library, but maybe you're right :\ i'll give it a try

Comment: nope, doesn't seem to work :(